# Compiling Python 3.5 code with Cython and MinGW on Windows 7 (64bit)

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, cython

I am trying to setup a workflow for generating .pyd and .exe files from Python 3.5.1 code with Cython and MinGW on Windows 7 64bit.

I have a simple example.py file:

```
def hello(x):
    print("Hello",x)

if __name__=='__main__':
    hello("World!")
```

From other threads on SO, I got the Cython command below, which generates an .c file w/o warnings.

```
cython --embed -o example.c example.py
```

When I invoke gcc, I get the following warning and don't quite know if these are critical.

```
gcc -c -IC:\Python35\include -o example.o example.c

In file included from C:\Python35\include/Python.h:65:0,
                 from example.c:4:
C:\Python35\include/pytime.h:113:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside pa
rameter list [enabled by default]
     _PyTime_round_t round);
     ^
C:\Python35\include/pytime.h:113:5: warning: its scope is only this definition o
r declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
C:\Python35\include/pytime.h:118:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside pa
rameter list [enabled by default]
     _PyTime_round_t round);
```

When I use gcc to generate the .pyd file, I get a bunch of undefined reference messages and ld exits with an error status.

```
gcc -shared -LC:\Python35\libs -o example.pyd example.o -lpython35

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2e2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_Pack'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x3bc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCode_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x409): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_Pack'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x4f3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x53a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBytes_FromStr
ingAndSize'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x5a5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_Create
2'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x5e5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_GetDic
t'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x630): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_AddMod
ule'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x682): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_SetAtt
rString'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x6ef): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_SetAtt
rString'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x715): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_GetMod
uleDict'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x756): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemS
tring'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x778): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItemS
tring'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x87e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0xa7f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xac8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0xc04): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0xc0f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportErr
or'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xc21): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xc5f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_NameError
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xc78): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xcb8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Call'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xcc4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyThreadState_G
et'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xcd7): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_CheckRecurs
ionLimit'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xcf1): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_CheckRecurs
iveCall'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xd2a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyThreadState_G
et'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xd3d): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_CheckRecurs
ionLimit'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xd4b): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_CheckRecurs
ionLimit'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xd57): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_CheckRecurs
ionLimit'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xd6d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyThreadState_G
et'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xd86): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0xd99): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_SystemErr
or'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xdab): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xdcb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_AddMod
ule'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe02): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAtt
rString'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe25): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe3b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe61): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe77): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe83): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_Attribute
Error'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe8d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Exception
Matches'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xe9d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Clear'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xeaa): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_Ready'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xece): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_SetAtt
rString'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xf95): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromS
tring'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0xfbb): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0xfc5): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0xfcc): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0xffd): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x107e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_Inte
rnFromString'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x10e7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeErro
r'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x10f9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetStrin
g'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x11ac): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeErro
r'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x11be): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetStrin
g'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1240): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1272): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x12c1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeErro
r'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x12d3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetStrin
g'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x12fe): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeErro
r'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1310): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetStrin
g'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1398): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x13a2): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x13a9): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x13c8): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1485): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x148f): more undefined references to `_imp___Py_None
Struct' follow
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x14ab): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeErro
r'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x14bd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetStrin
g'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1572): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1598): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x15a2): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x15be): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeErro
r'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x15d0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetStrin
g'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1685): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x16ab): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x16d0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeErro
r'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x16e2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetStrin
g'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1778): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x17c3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_From
String'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x17d8): undefined reference to `_imp___PyObject_GC_N
ew'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1913): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GC_Tr
ack'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1cef): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Free'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1d13): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GC_Un
Track'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1d2a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Clear
WeakRefs'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x1d42): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GC_De
l'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2030): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMethod_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x203f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInstanceMeth
od_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2048): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x206c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMethod_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x207b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInstanceMeth
od_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x20a2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_From
Format'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x20c5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCFunction_Ca
ll'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x20d4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCFunction_Ca
ll'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x211b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItem
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x216e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_Type
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2184): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_Type
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x21bb): undefined reference to `_imp___PyUnicode_Rea
dy'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x21e3): undefined reference to `_imp___PyUnicode_Rea
dy'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x260b): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2625): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2650): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_RichC
ompare'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x286b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x299f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Realloc'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2a79): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_From
String'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2ab2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_From
Format'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2ac4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_From
String'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2b60): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCode_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2cca): undefined reference to `_imp__PyThreadState_
Get'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2ce7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFrame_New'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2d08): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTraceBack_He
re'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2da1): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_SetProgramN
ame'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2da8): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2dc8): undefined reference to `_imp__PySys_SetArgv'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2de8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2df3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Print'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2e3a): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2e77): undefined reference to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2e7e): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_GetVersion'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2e9f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2eed): undefined reference to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'

example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2f0d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_WarnEx'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2f5a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_Inte
rnFromString'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2f9f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_Deco
de'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2fc5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_From
StringAndSize'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x2feb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBytes_FromSt
ringAndSize'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x3028): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_TrueStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x3039): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_FalseStruc
t'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x304c): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct
'
example.o:example.c:(.text+0x306b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_IsTru
e'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

What do I have to change im my workflow to generate a standalone .exe file?

Comment: Try adding `-shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Wl,--enable-auto-import` to the link command

Comment: This does not change anything.

Comment: are both gcc and python 64bit versions?

Comment: Python definitely is 64bit, but I'm not sure about gcc. gcc --version gives me 4.8.1, from MinGW Installation Manager I guess it's rather 32bit. Where do i get a 64bit version of MinGW? Or should i switch to Python 32bit?

Comment: I would use msys2. You can then choose to install gcc (64bit but linked to libmsys) and equally mingw32 & mingw64. I am in exactly the same issue atm and have reverted to 32bit py34. This post should allow me to go to 64bit py34. But right now mingw cannot tolerate py35 extensions due to a change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With help  from J.J. Hakala, I found the following commands to produce the desired output files:

**pyd 32bit**

```
cython -o example.c example.py
gcc -c -Ofast -IC:\Python35-32\include -o example.o example.c
gcc -shared -LC:\Python35-32\libs -o example.pyd example.o -lpython35
```

**pyd 64bit**

```
cython -o example.c example.py
gcc -c -DMS_WIN64 -Ofast -IC:\Python35\include -o example.o example.c
gcc -shared -LC:\Python35\libs -o example.pyd example.o -lpython35
```

**exe 64bit**

```
cython --embed -o example.c example.py
gcc -municode -DMS_WIN64 -mthreads -Wall -O -IC:\Python35\include -LC:\Python35\libs example.c -lpython35 -o example.exe
```

Thanks a lot to J.J. Hakala for your support.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to build a Cython based module for python 3.4 (64bit) with gcc 5.3.0 (64bit, seh)

First steps,

1. moved *python3.lib* and *python34.lib* away from *c:\Python34\libs* (for example a subdirectory there)
2. copied *python34.dll* from *C:\Windows\System32* to *c:\Python34\libs* using windows explorer (has to 64bit application).

When using cython with **--embed**

```
cython --embed test.py
g++ -municode -mthreads -Wall -O -I/c/Python34/include -L/c/Python34/libs test.c -lpython34 -o test.exe
```

When creating a module,

```
cython test.py
gcc -mdll -O -Wall -I/c/Python34/include -c test.c
gcc -shared -L/c/Python34/libs test.o -lpython34 -o test.pyd
```

gcc seems handle *dll* files better than *lib* files when linking.

Comment: I was able to compile a simple test, but testing the executable or the module leads to a crash.

Comment: I switched to 32bit Python and managed to generate and launch a example.pyd file (without crash). However, generation an .exe file with the command mentioned above gives me `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-municode'`

Comment: w/o the -municode, i get `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`. With the gcc 5.3.0 (64bit) I am able to produce pyd and exe file, but both crash.

Comment: @Juergen I added flag `-DMS_WIN64` and now I seem to be able to build cython based exe / module for 64bit python 3.5